# Declaring global enumerated arrays c++

Tags: c++, arrays, enums, header, global

I'm working on a system of arrays to function as an inventory, I need the array to have global scope so that it can be modified throughout the program. I have it declared w/ its enumerators in a header file like so:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#ifndef ITEMSARRAY_H
#define ITEMSARRAY_H

using namespace std;

enum Weapons
{
    LASER_RIFLE,
    LASER_SWORD,
    LASER_PISTOL,
    PLASMA_LAUNCHER,
    MAX_ITEMS
};

bool items[MAX_ITEMS];
    items[LASER_RIFLE] = true;
    items[LASER_SWORD] = false;
    items[LASER_PISTOL] = false;
    items[PLASMA_LAUNCHER] = true;


#endif
```

however this throws me an error on the lower statements because its trying to declare it as its own array or because its trying to initialize the value to the enum.I can put it in a function and resolve this problem like so:

```
void defineItemArray(bool items[MAX_ITEMS])
{
    items[LASER_RIFLE] = true;
    items[LASER_SWORD] = false;
    items[LASER_PISTOL] = false;
    items[PLASMA_LAUNCHER] = true;
}
```

the problem with this is that is then when i try to use the function the argument items does not pull the array like so:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "itemsArray.h"

using namespace std;

void playerInventory()
{
    defineItemArray(items);
    for (int item = 0; item < MAX_ITEMS; ++item)
        if (items[item] == true)
        {
            switch (item)
            {
            case 0:
                cout << "Laser Rifle\n";
                break;
            case 1:
                cout << "Laser Sword\n";
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Laser Pistol\n";
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "Plasma Launcher \n";
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Error";
                break;
            }
        }
        else
            cout << "Not in Inventory\n";
}

void playerGet()
{
    defineItemArray(items);
    cout << "You have found a Laser Sword.\n";
    cout << "Laser Sword added to inventory.\n";
    items[LASER_SWORD] = true;
}


int main()
{
    playerInventory();
    playerGet();
    playerInventory();
    return 0;
}
```

the **item** throws an undefined error, making the function useless. I'm not sure what I'm missing, but if I can get past this roadblock i can finally have this inventory system finished.

Comment: You have the following line in two different places `defineItemArray(item);` I'm assuming it should be `defineItemArray(items);`

Comment: It is, but I changed it and it still throws an undefined error for items, this time just for the one in the argument.

Comment: You cannot do assignments in the global scope

Comment: @NathanOliver, I can work around that, I really just need to know why its showing items as undefined, after i fix that i think i can work the rest out.

Comment: @SawyerAdlaiVierra-Hatch 1st of all: Don't use global variables, but function parameters or class member variables instead!

Comment: Maybe you should show the exact error message. BTW - you have put `item` in bold but shouldn't it be `items` ? And... exactly how does your header file look after moving the initialization into a function? Does the header file still contain the line `bool items[MAX_ITEMS];` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

You can globally define the `items` array in itemsArray.c like this:

```
// itemsArray.c 
bool items[MAX_ITEMS] = {true, false, false, true};
```

To make the array accessible from other files add the following to itemsArray.h:

```
// itemsArray.h
extern bool items[MAX_ITEMS];
```

Include itemsArray.h in the file where you have to access the items array.

The function`defineItemArray()` is not needed.

*Note:*

- using global variables is considered as **"bad" design**
- using `extern` is considered as **"bad" design**

**Option 2:**

Refactor the `defineItemArray()` function so that it initializes an previously defined array:

```
void defineItemArray(bool items[])
{
    items[LASER_RIFLE] = true;
    items[LASER_SWORD] = false;
    items[LASER_PISTOL] = false;
    items[PLASMA_LAUNCHER] = true;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
void playerInventory()
{
    bool items[MAX_ITEMS];    // define the items array
    defineItemArray(items);   // initialize the items array

    for (int item = 0; item < MAX_ITEMS; ++item)
    ...
```

Comment: I tried method 1 and got this error:                                           1>itemsArray.obj : error LNK2005: "bool * items" (?items@@3PA_NA) already defined in inventoryTest.obj
1>C:\Users\Sawyer\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\inventoryTest\Debug\inventoryTest.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

but i don't define it anywhere else in the code.

Comment: @StillLearning Thanks, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. On an off note, do you know why this post got downvoted. Was it because i was asking about global arrays or because i made a formatting mistake in the post? I have the feeling this won't be the last time I need to ask for help and I want to make sure I'm doing it properly.

Comment: Don't worry about the down-votes. Some persons at this site down-votes all questions that they think are "simple". They seem to forget that some are newbees and consequently have problems with things that experts find simple. So don't worry, we all get down-voted by the "experts". However - you should have included the exact error message from the start and also just called it for a "compile error" instead of "items throws an undefined error". The words "throws ... error" makes us think about exceptions - not compile errors. But anyway - don't worry about the down-votes. :-)

Comment: @SawyerAdlaiVierra-Hatch have you managed to fix the link error?

Comment: @sergej - option 2 doesn't really reach the goal as it isn't the same items variable in all the code. The items array shall instead be in main() and then be passed to all functions, i.e. playerInventory, playerGet and defineItemArray. And all other functions in the program needing it.

Comment: @StillLearning You are right, option 2 just shows the basic concept.

Comment: @sergej, I did resolve the error using option one however, option 2 seems more suited to what i need, because it allows me to change initialization, but it gives the same error. I had to go pick up my sister so I haven't gotten to tinker with it, but in the given state it still produces an error.

Comment: @StillLearning, so I would put the array in main, then call defineItemArray(), then playerInventory(), the playerGet()?

Comment: @SawyerAdlaiVierra-Hatch If you are using option 2, make sure you delete the globally defined variable.

Comment: @sergej ok that makes sense. I think its close to what i had, probably a syntax error throwing a wrench in the works. So to make the defineItemArray() global i can just plop it in the itemsArray.h, or put in in another program and forward declare right?

Comment: @SawyerAdlaiVierra-Hatch put the defineItemArray() prototype into itemsArray.h and the defineItemArray() implementation into itemsArray.c. Include itemsArray.h in main.c.

Comment: @sergej, yah that works. Thanks again for your help. I feel I may have jumped in a bit to quickly, I started on the learncpp website a week ago, and just rushed down to arrays. May have missed a couple of core concepts. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

These lines:

```
items[LASER_RIFLE] = true;
items[LASER_SWORD] = false;
items[LASER_PISTOL] = false;
items[PLASMA_LAUNCHER] = true;
```

are invalid in a header file which is included in global scope.

Instead Place this code in a c-file:

```
bool items[MAX_ITEMS] = {true, false, false, true};
```

In the header file you shall only have this line:

```
extern bool items[MAX_ITEMS];
```

Then you can use the variable items in all c-files which includes the header file. And you don't need to pass the variable items to any functions as it is a global variable. BTW - global variables are in general bad but if you really want a global variable it can be done like that.